# How to build Grid layout menu item using Angular Material

Tags: html, css, angular, gridview, angular-material

sorry for the dumb question. I’m new here. Anyway, on to my issue.
i am having trouble creating angular material menu with **GRID VIEW**, not that default **LIST VIEW**. I'm stuck and i don't even know where to start. Conventionally, to create material menu in angular component, you import material in your angular project and component then within component.html, you do this...

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item disabled>
    <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
    <span>Check voice mail</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
    <span>Disable alerts</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

results to following view:
[List view menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxA0v.png)

but what i want is GRID View menu, looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0GoO.png) from Google

How can i implement that layout in Angular Material?
thank you, your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think `<mat-grid-list>` is what you're looking for.

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
    <mat-grid-tile>
      <button mat-menu-item>
      <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
  <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile>
  <button mat-menu-item disabled>
    <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
    <span>Check voice mail</span>
  </button>
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
    <span>Disable alerts</span>
  </button>
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
    <span>Disable alerts</span>
  </button>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is so close to what I want to achieve. however, I don't see icon labels after implementing your solution. Also, is there a way to customize floating menu width?

Comment: To avoid compilation error, import the MatGridListModule in feature or app module using import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!! it is the combination of @'s answer and ::ng-deep declaration in the CSS on mat-menu's custom class.
i.e.: component.html

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="custom-grid-menu">
    {{grid contents eg. Icons etc}}
</mat-menu>
```

Then on component.css

```
::ng-deep .custom-grid-menu{
    width: 100px;
}
```

then whole thing turns out great.